# Retrieve Stock Browser History?

Tags: file-system, stock-browser, history

I have a Galaxy S4 and today 45 browser tabs I've been using for about six months just disappeared (should have been bookmarking things, yes).

Is there a way I can retrieve my browser history via my PC so I can peruse through it and get an idea of what I'm missing?

Alternately is there any kind of way I can re-open my lost session?